# Java Desempenho de classes vazias e cheias de métodos

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, objetos

Se eu criar uma classe cujo objetivo a agrupar uma quantidade de métodos relacionados. Suponha uma Classe Boi{} e ela possuir diversos métodos mas nenhum elemento.

Por exemplo:

```
public class Ruminante{
      public String mugir(Animal animal){
            return "Muuu";
      }
      public void comer(Mato grama){
             //processa grama
      }
      public void darCabecada(Animal animal){

      }
      public void darCoice(Animal animal){

      }
}
```

E quando eu quiser chamar fizer:

```
public class Principal(){
       Boi boi = new Boi();
       Ruminante r = new Ruminante();
       r.mugir(boi); 
}
```

Qual a perda de desempenho? Há outras desvantagens em fazer desta forma? É muito pior do que se tudo na classe Ruminante fosse estático?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Métodos de instância de java são por padrão virtuais. Isso quer dizer que (salvo nos métodos estáticos ou marcados como `final`) sempre que um deles é chamado, há um *lookup* na tabela virtual do objeto para determinar se o objeto é realmente da classe Ruminante (e não de uma de duas subclasses) e dependendo da classe do objeto, é obtido o ponteiro para a função que deve ser chamada. Se a função é marcada como `static` ou `final`, então o *linking* é feito estaticamente, ou seja, o lookup na tabela virtual não é necessária, e o código é "mais eficiente".

Agora, tendo dito o parágrafo acima, para a grande, grande maioria das aplicações essa "perda de performance" não vai fazer diferença alguma. Salvo o caso em que você esteja executando a função num loop muito grande, sem outras chamadas, a perda de performance será insignificante. Na grande maioria dos casos, é melhor você escrever um código que faça sentido (que alguém possa endendê-lo e mantê-lo facilmente) que pensar em otimizações precoces. Ou de acordo com Donald Knuth: ["*Premature optimization is the root of all evil.*"](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) (otimização prematura é a raiz de todos os males).

Answer (score 9):

## Otimizações do Compilador

Uma vantagem do Java em relação a linguagens compiladas como C++ é que o JIT (*Just in time compiler*) consegue fazer otimizações a partir do *bytecode* no momento em que o código vai ser executado. Além disso, o próprio compilador Java está preparado para fazer várias otimizações já nas fases de compilação.

Essas técnicas permitem, por exemplo, transformar uma chamada a um método em código [*inline*](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/Inlining) dentro de um *loop*, evitando assim o *overhead* repetitivo de busca de métodos em chamadas polimórficas.

Tornar uma chamada de método em execução *inline* significa que o código do método é executado como se tivesse sido escrito diretamente no lugar onde o método é chamado. Dessa forma, não há *overhead* de busca do método a ser executado, alocação de memória, novo contexto de variáveis.

## Código que executa melhor

Há um artigo da Oracle intitulado [*Performance Techniques*](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PerformanceTechniques) (Técnicas de Desempenho) que fala explicitamente sobre "qual formato de código a JVM otimiza melhor" (*What code shapes does the JVM optimize best?*).

Vejamos alguns pontos:

- Métodos `static`, `private`, `final` são fáceis de colocar *inline*.
- Chamadas a métodos virtuais ou interfaces são frequentemente colocados *inline* se a hierarquia de classes permitir. Uma dependência é registrada se posteriormente uma nova classe da hierarquia for carregada.
- Se houver várias chamadas a um método virtual ou interface o código será otimizado com uma "checagem otimista". Se o tipo concreto mudar de entre uma chamada e outra, então o código será "desotimizado", fazendo então a busca na tabela de métodos virtuais. Por exemplo, num laço com uma lista de objetos de tipos diferentes. Veja [aqui](http://java.dzone.com/articles/abstraction-slows-you-down) um artigo demonstrando a diferença de desempenho.
- Chamadas a tipos "monomórficos" (isto é, não polimórficas) são mais fáceis de colocar *inline*.
- A primeira chamada a um tipo polimórfico pode gerar um *inline cache*, que fará com que as chamadas consecutivas ao mesmo objeto sejam mais rápidas.

## Otimização prematura

Apesar das "curiosidades" acima, concordo plenamente com o @carlosfiqueira: otimização prematura é ruim, sendo preferível escrever código legível.

Porém, toda regra tem sua exceção.

É importante lembrar que o desenvolvimento de um software é sempre baseado em suposições. A qualidade final do software depende do quanto essas suposições estavam corretas. Então, se o domínio do problema for estudado corretamente e sabe-se de antemão que determinada rotina vai precisar processar um grande volume de dados, é possível tomar certas decisões de arquitetura e implementação para garantir o desempenho, sem inibir uma boa modelagem.

Porém, isso só é viável quando há desenvolvedores experientes e especializados, capazes de escrever código robusto e "performático" em suas áreas de especialidade. Funciona mais ou menos assim: primeiro você escreve um sistema pensando no modelo, nas regras de negócio e na manutenibilidade. Então vai se deparar com diversos desafios, sendo um deles o desempenho, tendo que refatorar o sistema. Portanto, no próximo projeto, as lições aprendidas o ajudarão a tomar decisões de projeto (*design*) que provavelmente lhe pouparão de muita dor de cabeça.

Também é possível otimizar cedo quando o princípio de "resolver o problema primeiro e codificar depois" é seguido, pois através da análise estática de um algoritmo pode-se ter uma ideia dos possíveis gargalos.

É claro as primeiras otimizações não chegam em um nível tão baixo a ponto de se pensar bytecode, chamadas polimórficas e métodos `final`. Nem creio que é possível desenvolver um sistema totalmente otimizado de primeira, pois a experiência demonstra que em todos os casos muitos dos pressuspostos iniciais de um software mudam ao longo do projeto.

O que poderia dizer para sintetizar o meu pensamento é que os programadores experientes, ao invés de tentarem otimizar demais, simplesmente evitam escrever código ruim e cometer erros bobos que os iniciantes geralmente cometem, além de realizar testes com frequência ao invés de confiar cegamente que suas decisões estão sempre certas.

## Conclusão

Escrever código bom, legível e com desempenho satisfatório, não é algo que se possa alcançar com um conjunto de regras rígidas.

Entretanto, é, sim, possível otimizar o código para situações específicas.

Além disso, a experiência (unindo estudo e experimentação) fazem que o desenvolvedor naturalmente produza código de mais qualidade e rápido.

Na maioria dos sistemas cotidianos, um *profiler* certamente vai mostrar gargalos de processamento grosseiros num nível bem mais alto que chamadas de métodos, geralmente associados à Leitura e Gravação de dados (I/O), que resolvem 80% dos problemas de desempenho.

Comment: Muito bom, @utluiz. Para completar, apenas sugiro que você explique o que é inline, pois seu link, além de mandar para a página inicial do site, parece que iria mandar para um conteúdo em inglês.

Comment: @Pablo Valeu! Fiz alguns ajustes. Depois de mais de um ano tem muito coisa que daria para melhorar. :D